# Loading different textures on multiple GUILayout buttons in custom editor inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a custom editor and I want to have 3 separate textures (icon images) loaded on 3 separate GUILayout buttons, but struggling to do so. Let me explain: I am loading 3 prefabs from Resources/Prefabs folder and then I am assigning a GUILayout button for each prefab, just like this:

```
                 Object[] obj = Resources.LoadAll("Prefabs", typeof(GameObject));
                 objects = new GameObject[obj.Length];

                 for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length; i++)
                 {
                     objects[i] = (GameObject)obj[i];
                 }

                 if (objects != null)
                 {
                     for (int j = 0; j < obj.Length; j++)
                     {
                         if (GUILayout.Button("", GUILayout.Width(70), GUILayout.Height(70)))
                         {
                            selectedObject = objects[j];
                         }
                     }
                 }
```

**How would I load separate textures for each button?** Textures are located in Resources/Textures folder.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use a proper overload of `GUILayout.Button`? You should have a look at the doc of [`GUILayout.Button`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayout.Button.html).

For example,

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ScriptName))]
public class ExampleOnInspector : Editor
{
    public Texture[] icons;
    void Awake()
    {
        //Load textures into icons by `AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<T>(assetPath)`
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        if (GUILayout.Button(icons[0]))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the icon 0");
        if (GUILayout.Button(icons[1]))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the icon 1");
        if (GUILayout.Button(icons[2]))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the icon 2");
    }
}
```

PS:
If your textures are only used in editor scripts, I suggest you [put them in `Assets/Editor Default Resources`](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/where-to-install-your-assets-for-scripting-packages-editor-extensions.292674/). Otherwise they will be included in your runtime resources.